# Mono 2.8.2 System.buffer.blockcopy error

Tags: apache, mono, apache2, mod-mono

When testing a ubuntu server running apache2 and mono 2.8.2 in a high load environment, about every ten minutes, it would output the following error (with the last two error lines repeated about a hundred times afterwards).

```
Handling exception type ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message is Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: srcOffset
IsTerminating is set to True
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: srcOffset
  at System.Buffer.BlockCopy (System.Array src, Int32 srcOffset, System.Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count) [0x000b7] in /home/elliott/mono-2.8.2/mcs/class/corlib/System/Buffer.cs:103
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadAll () [0x00183] in /home/elliott/mono-2.8.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:259
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.CheckResponseInBuffer () [0x0002f] in /home/elliott/mono-2.8.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:120
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebConnectionStream:CheckResponseInBuffer ()
  at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (IAsyncResult result) [0x001a3] in /home/elliott/mono-2.8.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:476
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+SocketAsyncResult.CB (System.Object unused) [0x00000] in /home/elliott/mono-2.8.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:214
[Tue Mar 08 13:49:58 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Tue Mar 08 13:49:58 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
[Tue Mar 08 13:49:58 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Tue Mar 08 13:49:58 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was 1
```

Would this be an issue with something in my code somewhere, or is it a problem in mod_mono itself? It seemed to appear after putting a higher load on the server, and there were no reference line numbers to any of my source code files.

Also to note, after upgrading to mono 2.10.1, in small tests I instead get this error with every request (but I haven't been able to test any large scale load):

```
[Mon Mar 14 12:59:30 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Mon Mar 14 12:59:30 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug in [`System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadAll`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs) to me. Somehow I suspect that `readBufferOffset` has become negative, although it's not obvious how... (of course, this may have been fixed since 2.8.2...) The argument validation code for [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Buffer.cs) is pretty straightforward...

Comment: thanks. I was hoping that wasn't the case, but it looks like it could definitely be something in mono itself. Unfortunately variations of these errors show up in both mod_mono and mono-fastcgi for me, so I'll need to figure out how to work around them.

Comment: In [`System.Net.WebConnection`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/2.8.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs) on line 438, `pos` (offset) is set to -1 default, and then has several code paths (as unlikely as they may be, I don't know) where it does not change pos whatsoever. This error is fixed in 2.10.1, though.

Comment: actually, my mistake, it's still an issue in 2.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I may have fixed this some time ago in a [git pull](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/232) which got committed to Mono on 2012-03-01.  Unfortunately, this means it isn't in mono 2.10.8.1 (which many distros are currently at since mono 3 is still beta).